# Unwanted fast animation when collapsing navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift, animation, navigationbar

I have this weird problem when I scroll to collapse the navigationbar.
I have a view with a TableView, embedded in a navigationbar controller with large titles.
When I scroll my view to make the navigationbar collapse, the animation is very fast. 
It almost looks like lagging. 
I tried to look around but had no luck.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: After some debugging I've found out that the problem starts when I populate my TableView. If the TableView has not data to display, the NavigationBar collapsing animation works smoothly.
Still no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. You should set the top constraint of the tableview to the TopView and not to the SafeArea.